# Rails 4 - secure way to give some users admin privileges?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization

I have a Rails app where I want some users to be `super users` with special privileges, like being able to access menus where they can edit content of the site. I'm not 100% sure that my implementation is secure, or the `Rails way`. It looks like this:

I have created an environment variable using the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) where I store the email-address of the original site creator:

```
ENV["site_manager_email"]
```

As I understand it, Figaro's `application.yml` works like Rails `secrets.yml`. My user model have a site_manager `BOOLEAN` attribute. The original site manager should be able to add other site managers by setting this property to `true`. In my `user model` I have a method to check whether users are site managers or not, it looks like this:

```
def is_site_manager?
  self.email.eql?(ENV["site_manager_email"]) || self.site_manager == true
end
```

In my views where I have content that only site managers should be able to see I use the above method like this:

```
- if current_user.is_site_manager?
  SUPER SECRET CONTENT THAT ONLY SITE MANAGERS SHOULD SEE
```

In my controllers I'm also planning to add a before action filter to only give access to some actions.

So my question is, is this a secure way to do it? If not, what should I change?

And, is there a more `Rails way` to do it? If so, how does it look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using for authentication? Devise?

For admins you can look into roles-based authorization and CanCan:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

There is a RailsCast that will show how to set it up:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Once you install it and add a .role column to your Users you can create Ability.rb in your app/models that will look like something like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.role? :administrator
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
      can :create, Product
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with something more lightweight. CanCan looks interesting though, will check it out in the future.